# Generate 3D "matrix" with Pandas, based on comparing two dataframes [Python]

Tags: python

Good morning everyone. I am working with Python and Pandas.

I have two DataFrames, of the following type:

```
df_C = pd.DataFrame(data=[[-3,-1,-1], [5,3,3], [3,3,1], [-1,-1,-3], [-3,-1,-1], [2,3,1], [1,1,1]], columns=['C1','C2','C3'])

   C1  C2  C3
0  -3  -1  -1
1   5   3   3
2   3   3   1
3  -1  -1  -3
4  -3  -1  -1
5   2   3   1
6   1   1   1


df_F = pd.DataFrame(data=[[-1,1,-1,-1,-1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,-1,1],[1,-1,-1,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,-1],[1,1,1,-1,0],[1,1,-1,1,-1]], columns=['F1','F2','F3','F4','F5'])

   F1  F2  F3  F4  F5
0  -1   1  -1  -1  -1
1   1   1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1  -1   1
3   1  -1  -1  -1   1
4  -1   0   0  -1  -1
5   1   1   1  -1   0
6   1   1  -1   1  -1
```

I would like to be able to "cross" these two DataFrames, to generate or one in 3D, as follows:

[image: Matrix 3D]

The new data that is generated must compare the values of the **df_F** with the values of the **df_C**, taking into account the following:

- If both values are positive, generate 1
- If both values are negative, generate 1
- If one value is positive and the other negative, it generates 0
- If any of the values is zero, it generates None (NaN)

***True table***

Comparison of the data **df_C** vs **df_F**

```
df_C vs df_F = 3D
  +       +     1
  +       -     0
  +       0     None
  -       +     0
  -       -     1
  -       0     None
  0       +     None
  0       -     None
  0       0     None
```

You, who are experts in programming, could you please guide me, as I generate this matrix, I compare the values. I wish to do it with Pandas. *I have done it with loops (for) and conditions (if), but it is visually unpleasant* and I think that with Pandas it is more efficient and elegant.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is off-topic here: 
we deal with computer *science* questions, 
not programming questions (see our [FAQ]).
Your question might be on-topic on [SO].

Comment: (Note the hover of tag `python`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to observe that the relationship can be achieved by multiplication of signs. With `numpy.sign(x)` we get 0 if x is zero, 1 if positive and -1 if negative, since you check for sign equality, multiplication by the same sign value will always be 1, multiplication by 0 always yields 0 and multiplication by opposite signs yields -1.

```
import numpy as np
Cs = np.sign(df_C.values)
Fs = np.sign(df_F.values)
```

The next step is to make the correct kind of broadcast. Using `A[:, None]`, we introduce a new dimension after the first:

```
assert Cs[:, None].shape == (7, 1, 3)
```

So we will expand F with an additional dimension in the middle, so that we can do element wise multiplication of every value in the column of F with one value in the column of C. We also need to expand C, so that the last axis has just a single value.

```
F2 = Fs[:, None]
C2 = Cs[:,:, None]
```

Finally, we multiply and cache the intermediate values so that we can use `np.where` to replace 0 with None and -1 with 0. However, you should keep -1,0,1 as it uses less memory, avoids multiple copies and is easier to work with.

```
S = F2*C2
assert S.shape == (7,3,5)
S = np.where(S==0, None, S)
S = np.where(S==-1, 0, S)
```

Comment: Looks like a fine answer - I hope the mods will migrate this to [SO] which is more appropriate for programming questions. Anyway, you can mark your own answer as accepted - it's also encouraged. When it comes to programming, we like to deal with at most pseudocode on this site :)

Comment: Except for that its not the same person who asked... :o

Comment: Cassandra, your solution is flawless. Thank you very much.